# What Does the Bitwise Complement Function Do in a For Loop in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, bitwise-operators

Take this line of code for example:
`for(int i=n-1; ~i; --i)`
My question is what does the `~i` mean. What I already know is the for loops needs the following:

```
for (type var = ; condition; something to do with var) {
code here
}
```

But how is `~i` a condition?
All I know is `~i` returns the bitwise complement of `i`, or flip the bits.

Comment: In C++ all zero values will be converted to `false` and all non-zero values converted to `true`.

Comment: Anything can be a condition. In a boolean context any non-0 value is considered to be true, and 0 is false. So, as long as "~i" is not 0, the `for` loop continues iterating. If you think about what value `i` must have so that `~i` is 0, you will have your answer.

Comment: condition is boolean, and the value of ~i is considere as such.

Answer (score 3):

In the 2-compliment representation of integers this loop

```
for(int i=n-1; ~i; --i)
```

is equivalent to

```
for(int i=n-1; i != -1; --i)
```

Answer (score 2):

In c++, this loop

```
for (int i=n-1; ~i; --i)
```

will terminate when all the bits of the underlying representation of `i` are `1`s.

In c++-20 the underlying representation of an `int` is required to be `two's complement`. The only `int` with all bits set to `1` in this representation, is `-1`. So the loop effectively becomes

```
for (int i=n-1; i != -1; --i)
```

as @Vlad pointed out in their answer.

Note that implementations pretty much always use `two's complement` representation, but c++ did not require it before c++20.